# How to get html content in component from v-html?

Tags: vue.js

I want to get html content from v-html.

If I use slot, I have this.$slot.

What is analog for v-html?

Comment: please share some code

Comment: You would have to use a $ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) simply sets the element's `innerHTML`, which can be accessed through `this.$el.innerHTML`:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$el.innerHTML)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-access-v-html?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)